# Technique for correcting colour/brightness/exposure levels between two images?

Tags: image-processing, brightness

I've got some code for stitching images together, but as you can see from my results
[image]

my colours and lighting are different between the two pictures. Is there some well known technique for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poisson Local Color Correction technique is an alternative. You can Google that.

[**Here**](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/vision/sadeghi/images/Poisson%20color%20correction%20-%20proceedings.pdf) you can find a useful paper with a nice description.

HTH!